# Java regex : matching a char except when preceded by another char

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use String.Split() to split a query, in that case a HiveQL query.

The case I have is I want to split along `;` except when that `;` is preceded by a `\`.
My problem :

```
String.Split(";")
```

is not enough.

```
String.Split("[^\\\\];")
```

(i.e not a `\` followed by a `;`) applied on

```
select table; count table;
```

will give groups `"select tabl"`, `" count tabl"`, so I lose the character before the `;`.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for that:

```
String.Split("(?<![\\\\]);");
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/XuSe00).

Comment: And since this is a single char match, you don't need the square brackets

Comment: Split is not the solution when there is the possibility of multiple escape characters in a row.