# Rub regex: matching a char except when after by another char

Tags: java, regex, ruby

I need find a regex that splits a string on periods that are not immediately followed by a right parenthesis (`')'`) and keep delimiter '`.`' after split.

For example, if

```
str = "This is a great (feeling.) thing. It's very interesting."
```

the regex should split this into two strings:

```
["This is a great (feeling.) thing.", "It's very interesting."]
```

I tried from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985567/java-regex-matching-a-char-except-when-preceded-by-another-char) and swap it but not successful.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Something like `.+?\.(?!\))`?

Comment: @Sweeper it's not correct. I tried it but not show result

Comment: Did you split it? You should `scan` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to retain the '.' delimiter after splitting, but I do know how to put them back. I also appears that the spaces that follow the delimiter should be removed.

The following regular expression will split ensuring that the '.' delimiter is not followed by a ')'. You may end up with an extra empty string, which can be removed:

```
import re

str = "This is a great (feeling.) thing. It's very interesting."
l = re.split(r'\.(?!\))', str)
# results are: ['This is a great (feeling.) thing', " It's very interesting", '']
if len(l[-1]) == 0:
    l.pop(-1) # get rid of last, empty string
l = [s.strip() + '.' for s in l] # get rid of leading and trailing spaces and add back delimiter
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['This is a great (feeling.) thing.', "It's very interesting."]
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired result indicates the string is to be split on spaces following a period (with the periods retained).

```
str = "This is a great (feeling.) thing. It's very interesting."

str.split(/(?<=\.) +/)
  # => ["This is a great (feeling.) thing.", "It's very interesting."]
```

`(?<=\.)` is a *positive lookbehind*. `".)"` is irrelevant.

To respond to the OP's second comment below, if the string is to be split on periods that are not followed by a right parenthesis, one would write:

```
str = "This is a great (feeling.) thing.It's very interesting."

str.split(/\.(?!\))/)
  #=> ["This is a great (feeling.) thing", "It's very interesting"]
```

This regular expression reads, "match a period that is not immediatally followed by a right parenthesis", `(?!\)` being a *negative lookahead*.

Comment: Thank you @Cary. I just need not sepatate if .). not care about spaces. So I updated it to `str.split(/\.(?!\))+/)`. Do you know keep . after split?

Comment: Bui, `str.split(/\.(?!\))+/) #=> ["This is a great (feeling.) thing", " It's very interested"]`. That's not the result you asked for, as the periods have been removed and the second string begins with a space.

Comment: Thank Cary. `str.split(/(?<=\.) +/)` Not good when `str = "This is a great (feeling.) thing.It's very interested."` => `not match`. I updated my question. Space char is not related to my question

Comment: In that case you will have to change your question. I suggest you add as a second example the string in your comment that contains `"...thing.It's..."`.

Comment: How can you assume "The desired result indicates the string is to be split on spaces" . He is very clear in his question.

Comment: @Rajagopalan, I did edit the question, but the original text said he wanted to split the line to obtain the lines `"This is a great (feeling.) thing."` and `"It's very interesting."` (though Bui did not include quotes). As you see, the periods have been retained and the space in `"thing. It's"` has been removed.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Ah okay.